# Limit order in Coinbase Pro

Tags: python, coinbase-api, fee

I try to place post-only limit orders so that there would be no fee, and the following is the related statements:

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

spot_price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'BTC-USD')

priceStr = repr(float(spot_price.amount) - 25.0)
buy_order = primary_account.buy(amount = '0.001', currency = 'BTC', price = priceStr, post_only = True )
print("buy_order=", buy_order, "price=", priceStr)

However, it did not work as a fee of 0.99 is charged and also the price is higher.  

What could be wrong?
```

OK, now I realize the problem might be that I was using the Coinbase API keys, instead of Coinbase.Pro (previously, GDAX) API keys. I have generated Pro API keys and will retry tomorrow (as it seems that the change will take place tomorrow). Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Thanks, 
Sean

Comment: can you add a bit more information to clarify your question?

Comment: @Cut7er Sure. I am new to this api.

Comment: What price did you submit and what price did you execute at?  How much time passed between order submission and execution?

Comment: @John I added some details. Thanks,

Comment: @JohnZwinck I added more details. I know some important details were not logged, but if my buy order was treated as a limit order, it should not have been filled at a higher price or incurred a fee.